use a lookup column result to populate a text column in the same sharepoint 365 list
I have a Sharepoint List (Office 365) with a couple of Lookup Columns.  I need the data from one of these columns to populate a new column as text so I can use it in a formula.  Is this possible?
For example, I have the lookup Column "Calculated Customer Number" in a list called "Jobs" which pulls the customer number from another Sharepoint List called "Customers".  This works perfectly. I need the data from that lookup column to populate another single line of text column in the Jobs list called "Customer Number".  The data will be used in another column called "Job Number" to calculate a job number.
I've searched the internet to no real success and have attempted to create a Power Automate using Get Item, Update Item, and using the Patch Function in the calculated value of the column.  Any suggestions you could offer would be great because I'm pulling my hair out!


Are you using power apps customized form for this SharePoint list (you mentioned Patch Function in your question) or SharePoint default form? If you have already customized the form, you can achieve it using Power Apps else you can do it using Power automate. Let me know once so that I can suggest solution accordingly.

@GaneshSanap-MVP I was attempting to use a customized power app.  I also read that the patch function might work.  I'm pretty new to this, so I hope it makes sense.  I'm really looking for step by step instructions on how to create the Get Info and Update Info to work.  I end up with a variety of errors either syntax or field related.
